# How do I prevent ServiceStack deserializing empty request parameter values as null?

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, servicestack-text, servicestack-bsd

I have a very simple ServiceStack service which I am invoking it via `JSONServiceClient` and c# typed API.

However, when I have empty arguments in `Request` params, ServiceStack is deserializing this into null values. I have looked and it seems like in JSV it is by design but JSON should retain non null values as they are. I have now also set following two settings in `Global.asax.cs` but with no improvement:

```
JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
JsConfig.ThrowOnDeserializationError = true;
```

I'm using ServiceStack version 3.9.69 and IIS version 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to differentiate between Null and Empty Strings?
If not, then treat them as the same thing, you can check for them using string.IsNullOrEmpty(string str)

From a quick Google of the issue, it seems as a known problem, so you are going to need to work around it.  Perhaps before serializing the, configure null values to a string "NULL"?

Comment: Thanks Talon. I thought of that, but the semantics of null and empty is different and treating them as same I may run into issues in future. I can solve the problem using checking for null or empty both and treat them same way but as I said they are essentially different things. Would you share the link where you find in context of JSON , I did find that in context of JSV but not JSON.